# Azure Data Studio is not supporting any of the shortcuts in the documentation?

Tags: azure-data-studio

I am running `Azure Data Studio` on macOS. The simplest shortcut - to run the current query - is MIA.  I tried F5, control-F5, command-f5, Option-F5 .. nothing happens.  Is there any support for these at all?